# if not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am trying to read `ModelAndView` in `jsp` file and load CSS and JavaScripts using data in model, But its not happening. Can somebody suggest to me whether I am using tags properly in jsp.

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${data}">
    <c:if test="${entry == 'pageScripts'}">
        <script src="resources/core/js/application/" ${entry}></script>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${entry == 'css'}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/core/css/application/" ${entry}>
    </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

**Controller**

```
public class IntroPageController extends DefaultController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String navigateToDashboard(final Model m) {

       m.addAttribute("title", "Test Funda");
        return navigateWithModels(m, "introPage", "introPage", "introPage");
    }


}
```

**Default Controller**

```
public abstract class DefaultController {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DefaultController.class);

   public String navigateWithModels(final Model m, final String pageName,final String css, final String... pageScripts){
        m.addAttribute("pageScripts", pageScripts);
        m.addAttribute("pageName", pageName);
        m.addAttribute("css", css);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: Some grammatical errors and highlighted code sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can skip the reference to ${data} and use the attributes you added to the model directly.

So your JSP fragment would become:

```
<script src="resources/core/js/application/" ${pageScripts}></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/core/css/application/" ${css}>
```

You would have to change the reference locations depending on what values you are populating the attributes with.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally :

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${pageScripts}">
<script src="resources/core/js/application/${entry}.js" ></script>
</c:forEach>
```